# How does Intellij deploy to JBoss?

Tags: intellij-idea

I finally have my application in IntelliJ and deploying to JBoss. I'd like to get hot deploy working but it looks like I need to understand how IntelliJ and JBoss interact.

When I build my project in IntelliJ and then start JBoss, the ear file does not appear in the deploy directory so I assume that there is some magic that IntelliJ does so that JBoss reads from a different folder. What is happening during this step?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-jboss-server.html).

Basically, you need an exploded **Artifact** configuration with the directory name ending with **.ear**.

**Build | Make** performs hot deployment as well as **Update** action (which is configurable and can update only resources, resources and classes, optionally redeploy or restart the server).

Instead of copying your application to JBoss, IDEA runs it with appropriate parameters so that it uses Artifact directory instead. Configuration is very flexible and you can just change the artifact directory location to reside under JBoss directory.

Answer (score 45):

I know this is an old and apparently answered question, but unfortunately the links provided in the accepted answer didn't give me the simple details I was looking for. For anyone also trying to understand how IntelliJ IDEA deploys your exploded war to JBoss without copying files to the deployments folder, here's what I've found while deploying **locally** from IDEA 14 (EAP) to JBoss 7.1.1.Final:

- After you've created an "exploded war" artifact for your project (or it has automatically been created for you), IDEA will build your provided sources and place the output in the directory set in the artifact options (you can change this setting to place the output inside the deployments folder inside your jboss installation).
- IDEA will update your JBoss configuration file (/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml) and add a "deployment" node inside the deployments section. This entry simply defines a name, a runtime name and the exploded war root folder for your project, which will point to the output directory of your artifact set in IDEA.
- When JBoss is started (either manually or from your run/debug configuration in IDEA), it will automatically deploy your artifact. Be warned that if your files are in the output directory of your project and you clean it, JBoss will still try to find the directory, thus encountering errors in your next attempt to start it: `org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to mount deployment content`, `Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment` and `java.io.FileNotFoundException` to name a few.

Comment: This should be marked as answer as of 2015. Further details for bullet point 1: Your artifact options can be found here (IntelliJ v14): Tab at bottom "Application Servers" -> select your server -> click Edit configuration icon -> Select tab "Deployment" -> Click edit (a pencil icon) -> The setting is found in field to the right called "Output directory".

Comment: @Herick - any suggestion/resolution on you last bullet point? I am seeing same behavior - jboss is trying to deploy last version and seeing `FileNotFioundException`

Comment: @RonakPatel either you need to run your build again (maven? gradle?) so that the output files are there, or you could manually remove the deployment entry from the JBOSS config file.

Comment: I am doing clean install...new rev gets deployed fine but jboss also tries to install older rev - which is not there(updated by maven build)

Comment: @RonakPatel could it be that you left the old artifact configured in IntelliJ?

Comment: Hmm, artifact location is target dir which gets deleted on each clean install - I'll check .idea folder - if there is any tmp files related to old artifact

Comment: That was the deployment entry I mentioned :D

Comment: @Herick IDEA didn't update the standalone.xml file for me, so I had to change the **output directory** to match the JBoss deployment folder, any idea?

Comment: @Villat it's been some time since this was valid so I'm afraid I cannot guarantee 100% that it still is today, but were you running in standalone mode i.e. not domain?

Comment: @Herick yes, I was running in standalone mode, maybe something changed.