# How do you make this in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, intellij-idea

How would you make this in IntelliJ:

> EJB project
>   WEB project
>   EAR project

then deploy the whole app to Glassfish  with a single click on run? In eclipse I added the EAR project to glassfish with the plugin.

I have really no clue on where to start or how to connect the pieces in IntelliJ. Or, if you know about some Maven thing I could do to make the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) \ Artifacts. Set "Output directory" to `deploy` dir of JBoss.

See also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757619/how-do-intellij-build-artifacts-and-run-configs-work-when-using-maven

[How does Intellij deploy to JBoss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492520/how-does-intellij-deploy-to-jboss)