# Intellij-IDEA Wildfly Server Duplicate resource on server startup

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, wildfly

i'm trying to migrate an old Java EE project running on Wildfly server from Eclipse IDE to Intellij Ultimate IDE.

I managed to properly configure the server and the artficats needed to start my application, but every time i start my Wildfly server inside my Intellij Ultimate IDE, i get the following error:

```
D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.bat
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath path\to\user\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath835606521.jar com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 61015 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.WildFly11Agent
[2022-12-19 05:25:29,009] Artifact MyProject: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 9990
Detected server http port: 8080
Calling "D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56525,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:path\to\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar "
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56525,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:path\to\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar   --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED"

===============================================================================

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56525', transport: 'socket'
17:25:29,965 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final
17:25:30,627 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
17:25:30,638 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
17:25:30,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 22.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 14.0.0.Final) starting
17:25:31,733 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.14.1.Final
17:25:32,425 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:25:32,462 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
17:25:34,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content\45\dd237fa579ec67b846820741a8350364a118b0\content
17:25:34,130 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MyProject.ear")]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"MyProject.ear\")]"
17:25:34,136 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
17:25:34,161 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 22.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 14.0.0.Final) stopped in 6ms
```

Looking at my standalone.xml inside my server the problem seems to be located in the following section:

```
    <deployments>
        <deployment name="MyProject.ear" runtime-name="MyProject.ear">
            <fs-archive path="D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\MyProject.ear"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
```

Deleting those lines makes the server correctly start and deploying, but I have to do it every time I shutdown my server or restart my IDE

Is there a way to prevent this?

Also my main EAR out directory is set to
`D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments`
And i need that folder to be set to that path

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a sample to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is handling the EAR as both a [managed and unmanaged deployment](https://docs.wildfly.org/22/Admin_Guide.html#managed-and-unmanaged-deployments). The line below indicates that the EAR has already been saved into the server, and a saved copy is being loaded at bootime:

```
17:25:34,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\standalone\data\content\45\dd237fa579ec67b846820741a8350364a118b0\content
```

This one conflicts with the one in the `deployments` directory. The docs linked above explain why you may want to use a managed deployment (ex. distribute to a server group), but if you don't need that, you can switch to the unmanaged kind. Delete the `<deployments>` section in the config once more, and run this in the CLI:

```bash
undeploy MyProject.ear
deploy D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\MyProject.ear --unmanaged
```

Comment: I've tried to run your solution, but the next time i launch my server via Intellij IDE, it seems to trigger again a managed deployment for MyProject.ear
Is there a way to disable that and instead launch a unmanaged deployment?

Comment: I don't have IDEA Ultimate to test, but assuming you're using the WildFly extension to launch the server, on boot the extension will [deploy the application itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25038943/19546298). If so, you'll need to disable this and use another method to move the artifact to the deployment folder (ex. Maven goals), or not attempt to deploy the module from the startup CLI script.

Comment: Found my answer, i did not manage to fix the plugin, but i wrote two scripts that are launched on server start and server stop that copy the previous version of the standalone on start and then replace it on server shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and it was caused by the fact that the directory to which IntelliJ IDEA was deploying was the same used by the JBoss/Wildfly deployment scanner for autodeploying artifacts.
What worked for me was:

- delete all files related to the EAR from your deployments directory (I guess they're `D:\wildfly-22.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\MyProject.ear*` in your case)
- delete the `<deployments>` section added by IntelliJ IDEA from `standalone.xml`
- change the Run/Debug configuration in IntelliJ IDEA in order to make it deploy into another directory: in my case, it was a remote JBoss/Wildfly server, so I just had to change "Path from root" and "Mapped as" so that they pointed to another directory of the remote server, not sure how this should be done with a local JBoss/Wildfly installation (never tried)

That's it: no more "duplicate resource" error on JBoss startup for me after this.